# Single Page vs. Multi-page Websites

Tags: website-design

A colleague and I are tasked with creating a new website that will be used for configuring devices (hardware), displaying general as well as specific information.  He's a recently new comer to the web world, but has excellent organizational skills.

I have been in the web world for about 12 years (mostly back-end, but long enough to handle UI designs... sort of)

He is strongly suggesting that we develop the website with a single page format (ie, build a main page which will hold a non-changing header section, a dynamic content middle section and a non-changing footer section), then for every link that normally would take to a different content page, we would code it so though ajax calls we populate the dynamic context middle section.

Programmatically, I don't see any issues building it that way, but something about it making me dislike it (honestly, I'm not sure what it is).  I personally like the old fashioned way of building one page for every content change and going to the server to get the entire page.

The website we are tasked to complete is fairly technical and only people who have knowledge of the hardware the site exposes will use it.

I'm looking for advice from devs who have done both kinds of websites (single page and multi-paged) for the type of information and interaction I've described above.

PS. Editors, I don't think this question can be modified further to not make it opinion based.  If this change still does not make the question in line with this site's format, please be kind to direct me to one that will give me the information I'm looking for (as I have not found one yet).  Thanks.

PS #2: To be even more clear, the website will have the following features:

- Links that will display data for specific devices
- Page content for each specific device can be completely different from the content of another device
- A large portion of the data presented for a specific device will be fast changing (websockets technology will be used for that)

Comment: I used to build *reliable systems* for DEC and these systems had to perform every second of every day for years on end. Most of these were real-time machines and operated mills, glass factories, as well as scientific measures, flight and mission controls, and so forth. The key takeaway from that experience was simplicity and reliability of process as well as removing single points of failure. Ajax adds complexity. Simple HTML adds reliability.

Comment: Perfectly valid question, quite the dilemma, let's get on with it and let the information flow...

Answer (score 0):

Single-page pros:

- Smoother user experience when navigating between pages; browser doesn't have to dump the whole page and re-render it.
- Less data to transfer to the client when navigating between pages; pages load faster overall.
- Pages that have been requested can be stored in a hidden div while not in use, so if the user requests that page again you can skip a trip to the server and just show it.

Single-page cons:

- Requires Javascript enabled at the client.
- Will add complexity to your site/app architecture as opposed to static pages which are easier.
- May be less or more SEO efficient than static pages depending on the architecture (I couldn't tell if your project requires SEO so this might not matter).

You can find more info, including a working single-page code example, in the answer that I posted [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66779/how-to-let-the-user-decide-to-keep-the-state-of-a-site/66829). You can find a related question with some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862054/single-page-application-advantages-and-disadvantages).

Comment: This answer helped us make the decision to go with the Multi-Page design for this particular project.  Can someone mark it as accepted?  I don't have enough rep points to do that yet.